# "While" loop is returning one value when there should be two

Tags: php, mysql

Argh.  I have no idea why this isn't working:

I have a database with only 2 rows.  One of the db columns stores a time+1 hour.  I would like to query the db and, for each row that has a stored time that's older than the current time, send me a message.  Basically it just delays sending the messages for 1 hour from the time they're stored.

What happens is that it only sends ONE email.  Both values in 'storedtime' are older (smaller) than the present time.  But only one message goes out.  What the heck have I missed here?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM db";
$result=@mysql_query($query);
$num=@mysql_numrows($result);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$i = 0;
$time = time();
while($i < $num)
    {
        if(($row['storedtime']) <= $time)
        {           
        mail("myemailaccount","Subject","Message here, etc.", $headers);
        }

    $i++;
    }
```

Comment: put `$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);` after `while($i < $num)`. To be honest you should go to manual `mysql_fetch_array` and read examples.

Comment: I would select the correct rows from the db directly and use a foreach loop to go through the results. And of course dump the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and add proper error handling.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2):

I recommended to use `mysql_fetch_array($result)` in the while loop

Then, it should like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM db";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$time = time();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        if(($row['storedtime']) <= $time)
        {
              mail("myemailaccount","Subject","Message here, etc.", $headers);
        }
}
```

Hope it helps.

You can check the following examples from the documentation site. Furthermore, it is important to read the section **Suggested alternatives** (**MySQLi** or **PDO_MySQL**, instead). http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: do not teach people bad habbits. Remove '@' from `mysql_query()` and handle errors correctly. And in general forget about `mysql_`. It is deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments.  I didn't know that these were deprecated.  I will look into other options!  Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so I've been trying to wrap my head around mysqli and finding it fairly opaque.  Would anyone out there be able to offer an equivalent line to the "while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {etc...} that will accomplish this?  And (I was playing around with the "while" suggestion too...am I right to think that this will only allow for ONE line of text?  I seem to be only able to get it to work if one of the two lines has a timestamp less than current time.  Not if both do.  It only goes through the first and then stops.  Is there a way to do an equivalent to the "$i++" or something? Thx!